# Making cakephp 2 web secure not to be detected as "less secure app" by Google

Tags: security, cakephp, gmail, cakephp-2.0

I have a cakephp 2 web in which I want to send a confirmation email, but this action ends up falling in "SMTP server did not accept the password" error. I have read this issue may be cased by the fact that the app is being detected by Google as a 'less secure app' and, therefore, Google blocks this action. I know this option of blocking less secure apps can be disabled, but instead of doing that, I'd like to know if there is any way of modifying my app so that it is no longer detected as a less secure app (by increasing its security or fixing the points that make Google detect it as less secure).

In case it gives more clues about a way of increasing the security, I have this in my email.php

```
public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'sender' => 'XXX@gmail.com',
        'replyTo' => 'XXX@gmail.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'XXX@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'YYY',
        'client' => null,
        'tls' => true
    );
```

And this in the controller in which I send the email

```
            $email = new CakeEmail('smtp');
            $email->emailFormat('html')
                    ->subject(__('SUBJECT'))
                    ->to($user['User']['email'])
                    ->from(array('XXX@gmail.com' => 'XXX'))
                    ->send();
```

Comment: As far as I know, basically *everything* outside of GMail is considered by Google to be a "less secure app".

Comment: Ackchyually... :) [**Google starts being your friend again**](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en) when you use [**OAuth authentication**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol), however CakePHP's SMTP transport doesn't support that.

Comment: Ok, then I guess I will have to admit those "less secure apps" in my account. Thank you for your answers!